# two divs on the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use jquery mobile. Inside my page-header I want to put two divs one accross another (on the same line) left one would contain background image and right some button. So I tried

```
<div class="ui-block-a" style="background-image:url('/img/someImg.png'); width:100%;height:50px; style="float:left;"> LEFT </div>
<div class="ui-block-b" style="float:right;>
    <a href="" data-role="button" data-theme="d">button on the right </a>
</div>
```

but button always shown down.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have some typos in your markup:

```
<div class="ui-block-a" style="background-image:url('/img/someImg.png'); width:100%;height:50px; style="float:left;"> LEFT </div>
```

Should be:

```
<div class="ui-block-a" style="background-image:url('/img/someImg.png'); width:100%;height:50px;float:left;"> LEFT </div>
```

You are also missing a closing parenthesis on the `style` portion of your second `div`.

Second, you have your background image size set to 100%, meaning it's going to take up 100% of the width, leaving no room left for your other `div` element. Reduce the width of the first `div` and the second will fall into place.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xs24/

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are setting the width of first div to 100% and there is also typo,try this

```
<div class="ui-block-a" style="background-image:url('/img/someImg.png'); width:50%;height:50px;float:left;"> LEFT </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="float:left;>
        <a href="" data-role="button" data-theme="d">button on the right </a>
    </div>
```